# Moving average with a difficult condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I hope someone will help with the advice ...

There is a table in df:

```
   Axis  Player_1 Player_2      RES     Aver_RES1   Aver_RES2
        1       1       2       0               
        2       2       1       1               
        3       1       3       1               
        4       3       1       0               
        5       2       4       1               
        6       4       2       0               
        7       2       8       1               
        8       8       2       0               
        9       1       8       0               
        10      8       1       0               
        11      3       5       1               
        12      5       3       0               
        13      1       8       1               
        14      8       1       0               
        15      1       4       1               
        16      4       1       0               
        17      2       1       1               
        18      1       2       0       0.6667      1
```

In column Player_1, Player_2 coded players. In RES - the result of the game (1 - the first player wins, 0 - the first player loses). Each game is duplicated (player_1 becomes player_2).
And I need to calculate how the Player_1 played by this moment, with those with whom the Player_2 played. And also for the Player_2.
For example, consider the 18 line. 
Player_1 (1) played with 3, 4, 8 players. Player_2 (2) played with 4, 8 players. Their common opponents are 4, 8 players.

How could this be (but with replacement ?????):

```
df['Aver_RES1'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[
        (

            & (df.Player_1 == x.Player_1)
            & (df.Player_2 == ??????)
        ),
        "RES",
    ].mean(),
    axis=1,
)

df['Aver_RES2'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[
        (

            & (df.Player_1 == x.Player_2)
            & (df.Player_2 == ??????)
        ),
        "RES",
    ].mean(),
    axis=1,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Aver_RES1'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[
        (

            & (df.Player_1 == x.Player_1)
            & (df.loc[(df.Player_1 == x.Player_1)].Player_2.isin(df.loc[(df.Player_1 == x.Player_2)].Player_2.unique()))
        ),
        ),
        "RES",
    ].mean(),
    axis=1,
)
```